# Почему reactjs setState возвращает предыдущее значение?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Мне нужно изменять `state` по клику. У меня есть такой код:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
   getInitialState : function() {
      return {value : 0}
   }
   changeState : function(event) {
      this.setState({value : event.target.id}) ;
   }
   render : function() {
      <a id="1" onClick={this.changeState}>Change</a>
   }
}) ;
```

Но изменение срабатывает только после первого клика, первый клик я получаю `0`, второй клик, я получаю `1`.

Я перечитал доку где сказано не использовать `setState` напрямую, поэтому я использовал `replaceState`, но и он по прежнему возвращает предыдущее значение. Как с этим бороться?

Comment: А как вы проверяете состояние компонента?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Этот код вообще не работает, т. к. нет `return`. И предлагаю добавить в вопрос работоспособный сниппет. И ещё, не видел в доке рекомендацию не использовать `setState` - точно не путаешь с рекомендацией не использовать `state` для записи?

Answer (score 4):

У setState есть довольно редко упоминаемый второй параметр, который является обычной callback функцией. Вы можете отлавливать новое состояние компонента уже там `this.setState({/* new state */}, callback)`.

```
var Component = React.createClass({
   getInitialState : function() {
      return {value : 0}
   }
   changeState : function(event) {
      this.setState({value : event.target.id}, function() {
       /* Получаем измененное значение state */
       console.log(this.state.value);
      }) ;
   }
   render : function() {
      return <a id="1" onClick={this.changeState}>Change</a>
   }
}) ;
```

Либо формируем новый объект state, а только потом записываем его:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
   getInitialState : function() {
      return {value : 0}
   }
   changeState : function(event) {
      /* формируем новый state */
     let nextState = Object.assign({}, this.state, { value: event.target.id });

      /* получаем будущее значение state */
      console.log(nextState.value);

      /* записываем новый state */
      this.setState(newState);

   }
   render : function() {
      return <a id="1" onClick={this.changeState}>Change</a>
   }
}) ;
```

Недавно делал [небольшой перевод про работу state](https://medium.com/@kanby/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-state-%D0%B2-react-js-d179a1fcefcb#.482ql190z). Возможно пригодится

Comment: Можно было бы и провести небольшую выдержку из статьи.

Comment: С удовольствием :-)

Answer (score 3):

Судя по всему, вы столкнулись с тем, что значение `this.state` меняется не мгновенно после вызова `this.setState()`. В тоже время, такое поведение является **штатным** (см. [документацию](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate)):

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.

Есть у меня такое чувство, что вы неправильно используете состояние компонента. К сожалению, без нормального описания исходной проблемы давать какие-то советы бессмысленно.